# jffs2_gcd_mtd1 CPU load

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu-usage

On debian/ubuntu9

What is  jffs2_gcd_mtd1 and why is it using CPU so extensively?

Is it related to apache or mysql continuous usage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jffs2 is a [journaling flash filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFFS2)  Are you trying to access a flash memory device?

Comment: Yes, the wwwroot is on a flash drive. That's half of the question answered. Big thanx.

But why 100% CPU ??

Comment: http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

I am trying to solve exactly the same problem... 4 years late :-(